# Filtering todos assigned to the user (hidden and displayed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of `users` and`todos`. There are objects in the todos array and todos and user ids in them. I display users and their todos. When I click on a user, it hides his todos.

> Problem: How to set up filtering so that clicking the user again shows his todos. A disabled user obtains a class with the opacity property.

**Intended effect**:

1. I click the user (id 1)
2. Hide todos assigned to this user (only todos for the user (id2) and user (id3) are visible
3. Click the user (id2)
4. Hide the todos assigned to this user (only todos for a user (id3) are visible)
5. Click user (id1) again
6. Displays hidden todos for this user (user todos are visible (id1 and id3)

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-s7aags

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Martin'
        }, {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Gregor'
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Paul'
        }
      ],
      todos: [
        {
          user_id: 3,
          todos: ['swim', 'feed']
        }, {
          user_id: 1,
          todos: ['sleep', 'read']
        }, {
          user_id: 2,
          todos: ['drinking', 'dancing']
        }
      ],
      hideTodosUserId: ''
    };
  }

  filterTodos = (userId) => {
    console.log(userId);
    const hideTodos = this.state.todos.filter(item => item.user_id !== userId);
    console.log(hideTodos);

    this.setState({todos: hideTodos, hideTodosUserId: userId})
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.users.map(user => {
            return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)} className={this.state.hideTodosUserId === user.id
                ? 'hideTodos'
                : ''}>{user.name}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
      <ul>
        {
          this.state.todos.map(items => {
            return <li key={items.id}>{items.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>)}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.hideTodos {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this have to be done with javascript? Could you not just set a `hide` class on the users `ul` and toggle it? - filtering the `todos` seems like a bit of overkill, since you show all the `todos` to start with

Comment: Definitely nothing wrong with filtering, certainly not overkill. The issue is that you are overwriting your original state. instead of filtering todos in your setState call, filter them in render

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing the original list of TODOs with the filtered one, making imposible to get back the TODOS from the selected user. Try to filter them in render and saving the selected  `user_id` like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: "Martin" },
        { id: 3, name: "Gregor" },
        { id: 2, name: "Paul" }
      ],
      todos: [
        { user_id: 3, todos: ["swim", "feed"] },
        { user_id: 1, todos: ["sleep", "read"] },
        { user_id: 2, todos: ["drinking", "dancing"] }
      ],
      selectedUserIds: []
    };
  }

  userIdHandler = userId => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      // Get the current index of the selected user id, if it doesn't exist it'll be -1
      const userIdIndex = prevState.selectedUserIds.indexOf(userId);
      const newSelectedUserIds = [...prevState.selectedUserIds];
      if (userIdIndex === -1) {
        // Add the selected id
        newSelectedUserIds.push(userId);
      } else {
        // Remove the selected id using the previously found index
        newSelectedUserIds.splice(userIdIndex, 1);
      }
      return {
        selectedUserIds: newSelectedUserIds
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.users.map(user => {
            return (
              <li
                key={user.id}
                onClick={() => this.userIdHandler(user.id)}
                className={
                  this.state.selectedUserIds.includes(user.id)
                    ? "hideTodos"
                    : ""
                }
              >
                {user.name}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos
            .filter(
              todos => !this.state.selectedUserIds.includes(todos.user_id)
            )
            .map(items => {
              return (
                <li key={items.id}>
                  {items.todos.map(todo => (
                    <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>
                  ))}
                </li>
              );
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I did not expect such an effect. It should be like this: I click the user (id 1) -> hide actions assigned to this user (only actions for the user (id2) and user (id3) are visible -> click the user (id2) -> hide the actions assigned to this user user (only activities for user (id3) are visible) -> click user (id1) again -> displays hidden activities for this user (user activities are visible (id1 and id3)

Comment: I've edited `state`, `userIdHandler`, and `render` to handle an array of selected ids. This should work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

As some answers already stated, your state doesn't allow to have the expected behavior.
I don't know if it's an option to you, but I modified your state, from that point on it is much easier. It could have been done in many different way (I don't know the state you want) but here is an example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [{id:1, name: 'Martin' }, {id:3, name: 'Gregor' }, {id:2, name: 'Paul' }],
      showingTodos: [{user_id:3, todos:['swim', 'feed']}, {user_id:1, todos:['sleep', 'read']}, {user_id:2, todos:['drinking', 'dancing']} ],
      hidenTodos: [],
      hiddenUserIds: []
    };
  }

  filterTodos = (userId) => {
    console.log(userId);
    const isHidden = this.state.hiddenUserIds.find(id => id === userId);
    if(isHidden) { // user was hiden
    const toBeShownTodos = this.state.hidenTodos.filter(item => item.user_id === userId);
    this.setState({
      users: this.state.users,
      hiddenUserIds: this.state.hiddenUserIds.filter(stateUserId => stateUserId !== userId),
      showingTodos: this.state.showingTodos.concat(toBeShownTodos),
      hidenTodos: this.state.hidenTodos.filter(item => item.user_id !== userId)
    })
    } else { // user was shown
      const toBeHidenTodos = this.state.showingTodos.filter(item => item.user_id === userId);
      this.setState({
        users: this.state.users,
        hiddenUserIds: this.state.hiddenUserIds.concat(userId),
        showingTodos: this.state.showingTodos.filter(item => item.user_id !== userId),
        hidenTodos: this.state.hidenTodos.concat(toBeHidenTodos)
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => {
          return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)} className={this.state.hiddenUserIds.find(id => id === user.id) ? 'hideTodos' : '' }>{user.name}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
        <ul>
        {this.state.showingTodos.map(items => {
          return <li key={items.id}>{items.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>)}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: And without modifying the state, without adding `hidden` it can be done?

Comment: Well without modifying the entire state, no, but without modifying the `state.users`, it can be done yes. You wil have to add extra information in your state. 
If you take my state `(users, showingTodos, hidenTodos)`, you can for example deduce the `hidden` property from the `(showingTodos, hidenTodos)` tuple. If you don't find any Todos of your user in `showingTodos`, it means it is hidden. I like the boolean better because it is explicit.

Comment: You can also add a `hiddenUserIds: []` or something like that. Then just add in this array every userID you want to hide, and remove every userID you want to show. That's what I said in my answer, there are many ways to do that if you change your state.

Answer (score 1):

You anyway need to keep track of hide/show status of a user. That is the only info you need to mutate.

Change type of `hideTodosUserId` to array of ids. On click, toggle the inclusion of selected user id in this array, i.e. add to array if absent, remove from array if present.

Use the `hideTodosUserId` array to filter out hidden user from complete list.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [{id:1, name: 'Martin'}, {id:3, name: 'Gregor'}, {id:2, name: 'Paul'}],
      todos: [{user_id:3, todos:['swim', 'feed']}, {user_id:1, todos:['sleep', 'read']}, {user_id:2, todos:['drinking', 'dancing']} ],
      hideTodosUserId: []
    };
  }

  filterTodos = (userId) => {
    this.setState(({hideTodosUserId}) => {
      hideTodosUserId = [...hideTodosUserId]
      const index = hideTodosUserId.indexOf(userId)
      if(index >= 0) {
        hideTodosUserId.splice(index,1)
      } else {
        hideTodosUserId.push(userId)
      }
      return {hideTodosUserId}
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => {
          return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)} className={this.state.hideTodosUserId.includes(user.id) ? 'hideTodos' : '' }>{user.name}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
        <ul>
        {this.state.todos
        .filter(ui => !this.state.hideTodosUserId.includes(ui.user_id))
        .map(items => {
          return <li key={items.id}>{items.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>)}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ruflba?file=index.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It removes some useless states and uses React.PureComponet for better performance.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const userList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Martin" },
  { id: 3, name: "Gregor" },
  { id: 2, name: "Paul" }
];
const todoList = [
  { user_id: 3, todos: ["swim", "feed"] },
  { user_id: 1, todos: ["sleep", "read"] },
  { user_id: 2, todos: ["drinking", "dancing"] }
];

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const users = userList.map(user => ({
      ...user,
      selected: true
    }));
    this.state = {
      users,
      todos: todoList,
    };
  }

  filterTodos = userId => {
    const { users } = this.state;

    users.forEach(user => {
      if (user.id === userId) {
        user.selected = !user.selected;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      users: [...users],
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { todos, users } = this.state;
    const validTodos = todos.filter(item => users.some(user => user.id === item.user_id && user.selected));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {users.map(user => (
            <li
              key={user.id}
              onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)}
              className={user.selected ? "" : "hideTodos"}
            >
              {user.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {validTodos.map(item => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              {item.todos.map(todo => (
                <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>
              ))}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And todos state doesn't change in any case. We don't need to put it in the state, and so we'd be better to receive it via props from its parent component. Or we can remove todos state and use todoList directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [{id:1, name: 'Martin'}, {id:3, name: 'Gregor'}, {id:2, name: 'Paul'}],
      todos: [{user_id:3, todos:['swim', 'feed']}, {user_id:1, todos:['sleep', 'read']}, {user_id:2, todos:['drinking', 'dancing']} ],
      hideTodosUserId: '',
      hiddenUsers: []
    };
  }

  filterTodos = (userId) => {
    console.log(userId);
    debugger;
    const newUsers = [];
    if(this.state.hiddenUsers.indexOf(userId) === -1) {
      this.setState({
        hiddenUsers: [...this.state.hiddenUsers, userId]
      })
    }
    else {
      newUsers = [...this.state.hiddenUsers]
      newUsers.splice(this.state.hiddenUsers.indexOf(userId), 1)
      this.setState({
        hiddenUsers: newUsers
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.hiddenUsers);
    return (
      <div>
       <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => {
          return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)} className={this.state.hiddenUsers.includes(user.id) ? 'hideTodos' : '' }>{user.name}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
        <ul>
        {this.state.todos.filter(item => this.state.hiddenUsers.indexOf(item.user_id) === -1).map(items => {
          return <li key={items.id}>{items.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>)}</li>
        })}
       </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Add an Array to the state which will contain the users to hidden `hiddenUsers`. Use this array to filter the todo results in render function.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          users: [{id:1, name: 'Martin'}, {id:3, name: 'Gregor'}, {id:2, name: 'Paul'}],
          todos: [{user_id:3, todos:['swim', 'feed']}, {user_id:1, todos:['sleep', 'read']}, {user_id:2, todos:['drinking', 'dancing']} ],
          originaltodos: [{user_id:3, todos:['swim', 'feed']}, {user_id:1, todos:['sleep', 'read']}, {user_id:2, todos:['drinking', 'dancing']} ],
          hideTodosUserId: ''
        };
      }

      filterTodos = (userId) => {
        if (userId !== this.state.hideTodosUserId) {
          console.log(userId);
          const hideTodos = this.state.todos.filter(item => item.user_id !== userId);
          console.log(hideTodos);

          this.setState({
            todos: hideTodos,
            hideTodosUserId: userId
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            todos: this.state.originaltodos,
            hideTodosUserId: ''
          })
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
           <ul>
            {this.state.users.map(user => {
              return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.filterTodos(user.id)} className={this.state.hideTodosUserId === user.id ? 'hideTodos' : '' }>{user.name}</li>
            })}
           </ul>
            <ul>
            {this.state.todos.map(items => {
              return <li key={items.id}>{items.todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo}</li>)}</li>
            })}
           </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I did not expect such an effect. It should be like this: I click the user (id 1) -> hide actions assigned to this user (only actions for the user (id2) and user (id3) are visible -> click the user (id2) -> hide the actions assigned to this user user (only activities for user (id3) are visible) -> click user (id1) again -> displays hidden activities for this user (user activities are visible (id1 and id3)

Comment: Use an array in order to save thr ids you have clicked.